# Simple example of a group where $g^2 = 1$ for all $g\in G$ but $G$ is not abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to find a simple example of a group where $g^2 = 1$ for all $g\in G$ but $G$ is not abelian. All the groups I can think about with that property are abelian.

Comment: Every group with this property is abelian. Hint for the proof: Take two elements $g$, $h \in G$ and consider $(gh)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $g^2=1$ for all $g\in G$, then every element is its own inverse. For all $x,y\in G$, we then have $xy=(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}=yx$.

Comment: Ah yes... I was actually meant to be showing the converse of this statement but in my head I thought this WAS the converse...thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one can show this by using the fact that for any group $G$, the map $\varphi \colon G \to G$ defined by $\varphi(g) = g^2$ is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.